# Is there a way to define haptic feedback on Android in xml?

Tags: android, button

Is there an easy quick way to add

> haptic feedback for buttons in xml

or do I really have to write custom haptic feedback code for every button separately.

I mean, do I really have to add haptic feedback code to each single button on each screen/activity on my code?

I almost can't believe that there is no other more practical way.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only thing similar to haptics that you can define in xml is an onclick listener:

```
android:onClick="myclick"

public void myclick(View v) {}
```

If you are looking for the same feedback for a few buttons, you could create a custom button class.

Comment: I do setOnClickListener for all my buttons to associate whatever code I need - will "myClick" be called in addition evertytime I put it in the xml or instead of all my setOnClickListener?

Comment: just think of myclick as the onClick(View v) that you override in the OnClickListener. Only one listener can be set per view. Now as far as if the xml listener is the one used depends on where in code you set the onClickListeners. In general, the xml onClick is assigned at run time.

Comment: So that means, I would have to just add the vibration code in my own onClick for every button manually? If there is no other "general" way - I guess I just have to do this. Thanks!

Comment: right. buttons can share the same onClick, so you would only have to implement the vibration once. If you need different behavior per button, just make switch checking the ids.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to provide haptic feedback is using the Vibrator service.

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(200);
```

You can also use v.vibrate(long[] pattern, int repeat) to provide different types of haptic feedback by turning the vibrator on/off/on/off/etc for specific time intervals.

Yes, if you want haptic feedback you will have to add it to every button you use. That's not difficult to do though... like Ian said, you can subclass button if you want a reusable solution. Otherwise, it's straightforward enough to add the vibrator code to the OnClick callback.